# Загрузка изображений для товаров через API vk.com

Tags: vkontakte-api

пытаюсь загрузить фото для товара согласно [инструкции](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files_2?f=6.%2B%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%2B%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%2B%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%2B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0)

получаю ссылку:

```
String uploadUrl = vk.photos()
        .getMarketUploadServer(userActor, vkConfig.getGroupId())
        .mainPhoto(isMain)
        .execute()
        .getUploadUrl().toString();
```

загружаю фото на сервер:

```
String uploadResultStr = Request.post(uploadUrl)
                .body(MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                        .addBinaryBody("file", convertedImageBytes, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "file.jpg")
                        .build())
                .execute().returnContent().asString();
PhotoUploadResult uploadRes = objectMapper.readValue(uploadResultStr, PhotoUploadResult.class);
```

сохраняю фото:

```
PhotosSaveMarketPhotoQuery savePhotoQuery = vk.photos().saveMarketPhoto(
        userActor,
        uploadRes.getPhoto(),
        uploadRes.getServer(),
        uploadRes.getHash()
);
if (isMain) {
    savePhotoQuery.cropHash(uploadRes.getCropHash());
    savePhotoQuery.cropData(uploadRes.getCropData());
}

savePhotoQuery.execute(); // ApiAccessException: Access denied (15): Access denied
```

Получаю ошибку **ApiAccessException: Access denied (15): Access denied**.

Токен получаю "пользовательский", оба метода, судя по доке, имеют одинаковый набор необходимых прав:
https://vk.com/dev/photos.getMarketUploadServer
https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveMarketPhoto
Но первый отрабатывает, а на втором ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста понять в чём дело.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено в обсуждении https://vk.com/topic-104669514_32932591?post=630

К списку параметров метода vk.photos().saveMarketPhoto к основной фотке необходимо добавить "group_id".